# CSS animation duration and speed

Tags: css, css-animations, marquee

I have some simple scrolling (marquee) text...

https://jsfiddle.net/kcbf0hsw/

I'm wondering why no matter what values I use for 'duration', the text always vanishes before 'completing the scroll'?

I always thought that

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 20.0s;
```

Would automatically set the speed so the animation finishes in 20 seconds.  Is that wrong?

I have tried many of the marquee libraries that are out there.  Ideally I'm looking for something that will work with dynamically changing text of various lengths.

Answer (score 1):

## marquee with css and also with javascript

I notice that the problem is that you have specified a fixed width for the text.

```
#Headlines{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*width:622px; This causes the problem*/
    z-index:0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000000;
    font-size: 24px;
-webkit-animation-name: scroll;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 20.0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    height:768px;
    background-color:grey;
  width: 1024px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#Headlines_bg{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 622px;
    height: 40px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    opacity:.3;
    z-index:-1;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

#Headlines_Container{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:622px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#Headlines{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*width:622px;*/
    z-index:0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000000;
    font-size: 24px;
  /*-webkit-transform:translateX(30%);*/
-webkit-animation-name: scroll;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 20.0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(38%);}
100% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);}}
```

```html
<div id="Headlines_bg"></div>
<div id="Headlines_Container">
<div id="Headlines">Pressure builds as COVID hospitalizations hit record highs in Ontario and New Brunswick+++Hamilton neighbourhood covered after plant malfunction sends 'beans raining down</div>
</div>
```

### update

A more controlled way to achieve the marquee effect is with javascript. Observe the following code is responsive.

```js
function markesina() {
        b = document.getElementById("m");
        //console.log(b.offsetWidth);
        console.log(b.scrollWidth, b.offsetWidth);
        b.animate(
          [
            // keyframes
            { transform: `translateX(${b.offsetWidth}px)` },
            { transform: `translateX(-${b.scrollWidth}px)` },
          ],
          {
            // timing options
            duration: 20000,
            iterations: Infinity,
          }
        );
      }

      markesina();

      window.addEventListener("resize", markesina);
```

```css
.marke {
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
```

```html
<link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />


<div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-6 mt-5" style="overflow: hidden">
          <p id="m" class="marke">
            Pressure builds as COVID hospitalizations hit record highs
            in Ontario and New Brunswick+++Hamilton neighbourhood covered
            after plant malfunction sends 'beans raining down  
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that!  If I remove that fixed width, there is a large delay before the text begins to scroll.  Do you know why that is?

Comment: update i added example with javascript

Comment: Got it working!

https://jsfiddle.net/bm0ruj1o/1/

No matter how much or how little text is there, the speed will always be relative!!
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

modify this line from

```css
100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

to

```css
100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-350%);
}
```

to make the writing disappear completely on the left

Comment: Thank you.  How can I make this dynamic so it will work with all sizes of text?

Answer (score 1):

try this it may work and stop displying the text after it finishes

`animation-fill-mode: forwards; animation-iteration-count: 1;`